# ArcSketch for version 10?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I was looking for a version 10 update of the [ArcSketch](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcsketch/index.html) (free) add-on/extension.

> ArcSketch allows you to sketch
>   features quickly, easily, and
>   intuitively without having to plan
>   ahead or deal with much ArcGIS
>   overhead. Afterward, the sketched
>   features can be converted into
>   standard features and shared with
>   others.
>
> ArcSketch allows you to create and
>   edit sketches without having to
>   specify the layer each time. You can
>   generate symbols that specify the
>   creation of feature classes and
>   attributes with defined structure.

Looking at the [download options](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/arcsketch/download.html), it only lists 9.1-9.3 versions.  According to the faq's, *appears* that the functionality has been rolled into "future versions".  Is it hiding somewhere is 10?

> ArcSketch is no longer a supported
>   product. Its functionality is being
>   incorporated into a future release of
>   the core ArcGIS Software.

If this does not exist in v10, does anyone know of alternatives (either ESRI or other software) that allows users to be able to quickly digitize and symbolize data without having to be an expert in the GIS software.  I hope to allow managers or operators to create GIS data quickly in a emergency response scenario, without being a GIS person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the ArcSketch extension myself but I'd say at least some of the functionality is now present in the feature templates and Create Features window at ArcGIS 10. [Here's](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisdesktop/archive/2010/07/28/Getting-started-with-creating-features-in-ArcGIS-10.aspx) a reasonable introduction and more info on the [ArcGIS 10 help site](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/What_s_new_for_editing/00qp00000006000000/)